# Collections.shuffle for list and refresh listview then

Tags: android

I want to random shuffle listview elements, I used collections.shuffle on list to do it but how I refresh the listview now?

```
Collections.shuffle(movieList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

listview is populated json with Volley library

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` should work. what is the problem?

Comment: @Amir_P problem that rows are not changing positions, I have array list (custom class), json > downloading to arraylist in loop > adding to array list.add and then notifyDataSetChanged. After all I want to shuffle it and notify but nothing is happening

Comment: Are you setting shuffled `movieList` to your adapters array? please post complete code of your adapter and activity thats not enough

Comment: Made shuffle before first time populate in listview, works ;)